# Backup Exec 2012: How to restore file from tape made on other server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backupexec

We have `Backup Exec 2012` on `Windows Server 2008` servers.

I am on "server A", I have a tape from "server B". On "Server A", I can inventory and catalog the tape, and see the backup sets on it.

But when I go to restore from this "Server B"'s tape, on "Server A", the backup sets I see on the device screen are not visible in the restore list.

So I am unable, so far, to choose the file to restore (or even see the backup set the file resides in, even though the tape is in the drive, the drive has been cataloged, etc)

This issue applies whether or not I work with encrypted tapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my work with BE 2012 so far, it appears the answer is:

- In the restore UI flow, you cannot see media. Rather, you see backup sets
- After cataloging a media, you can then, on the storage device view (the tape drive), see the backup sets on that media

**The important step that is easy to miss:** ***Before*** pressing Restore, click on the server name the media set is associated with. (You cannot do this later. You must select the server from the main list and then press Restore.)

- So the workflow to "restore by media" is:

  - Catalog media
  - Look at the backup sets on that media (the dates), write down the ones you are interested in
  - Click on the top menu tab Backup & Restore
  - Click on the server that the to-restore-media-set is associated with **(very important step!)**
  - Click the Restore button
  - Go through the restore work flow
  - When you get the "what files do you want to restore" open up the date range to include the date of the backup set (e.g. if the backup set is from 2010, open up the From date back to 2009 or so)
  - Choose the backup set(s) you want to restore
  - Continue with the restore process

The "suggestion for improvement" in BE would be:

- Add a "media view" to the Restore workflow
- On the media view (the Backup Sets list on the media/storage itself), allow me to right click on a backup set and trigger a restore from there

Answer (score 0):

In Symantec Backup exec on ServerA Export the encryption key and import it to ServerB.
This could be the issue as far as I remember the encryption key is under tools - Encryption keys